# what does || symbol means in Preg_replace() PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I was reading about how to make **preg_replace()** act like **eval()** function if we put the modifier /e this is my code:

```
$fa= '/site'.$_GET['1st'];
$sh= $_GET['replace'];
$ka= 'admin the best over the rest';
echo preg_replace($fa,$sh,$ka);
```

if the code running on site, it looks like :

```
www.site.com/a.php?1st=//e&replace=phpinfo();
```

but there is a problem that the modifier /e mustn't followed by any thing so it will work if we put || like this :

```
www.site.com/a.php?1st=||//e&replace=phpinfo();
```

so here is my question what is || here and how it works ??

im using windows 10 and php version 5.2

Comment: The `/e` modifier is obsolete. You should use `preg_replace_callback()`.

Comment: your implementation will allow for command injection

Comment: Unless you're intentionally writing in as many security holes as humanly possible, please don't do... literally anything you've put in that post.

Comment: Why not php version 7.2 >

Comment: Sorry but this post needs down, close and then delete votes. This is not a good contribution for future visitors. Its outright dangerous and offers close to none if no benefit at all next to the risks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`|` separates alternatives in the regexp; e.g. `/abc|def|ghi/` matches either `abc`, `def`, or `ghi`.

When you write `1st=||//e` the resulting regexp will be `/site||//e`. Two of the alternatives are empty strings, which will match the empty strings before and after each character. So this will call `phpinfo()` for each character in `$ka`.

Actually, you should get an error because you have two `/` at the end of the regexp. It should be `1st=/e` or `1st=||/e`.

Comment: man you just made my day,

Comment: thank you so much for this, have a nice day sir .